Concise Tokio equivalent of Go's ErrGroup
Coming to Tokio from Go I really miss ErrGroups which provide a great abstraction for a common concurrency pattern: "do some stuff in parallel, if any fails cancel all the others, block until all the tasks have terminated, then return the first error". An example (playground):
func runTasks() error {
    g, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(context.Background())

    for id := 1; id <= 3; id++ {
        g.Go(func() error {
            select {
            // Simulated work:
            case <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 500 * time.Duration(id)):
                if id == 2 {
                    return errors.New("simulated error")
                }
                return nil
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return context.Cause(ctx)
            }
        })
    }

    return g.Wait()
}

Is there a concise way to do this in Tokio, or perhaps even just async Rust in general? The best I've got so far is something like this (playground):
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut join_set = JoinSet::new();
    let cancel_token = CancellationToken::new();

    for id in 1..=3 {
        let child_token = cancel_token.child_token();
        join_set.spawn(async move {
            select!(
                // Simulated work:
                _ = tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500) * id) => {
                    if id == 2 {
                        bail!("simulated error")
                    } else {
                        Ok(())
                    }
                }
                _ = child_token.cancelled() => bail!("canceled"),
            )
        });
    }

    let mut final_result: anyhow::Result<()> = Ok(());

    while let Some(result) = join_set.join_next().await {
        match result.expect("join error") {
            Ok(_) => println!("Task completed successfully"),
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Task failed with error: {:?}", e);

                if !final_result.is_err(){
                    final_result = Err(e)
                }
                cancel_token.cancel();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Wait for remaining tasks to exit due to cancellation
    let _ = join_set.join_all().await;

    final_result
}

It seems pretty feasible to implement something like ErrGroup as a mini-library on top of the existing functionality but I'm wondering if there's something already available that I'm missing, or perhaps some reason why the example I linked is bogus and this is not actually feasible.

Something like this https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.31/futures/macro.try_join.html?

I've found this very helpful for similar usecases (in particular try_join_all) for similar stuff but it doesn't have the "wait for the others to complete" thing. I'm now realising though, that my desire to do that is kinda unusual for Rust. I have some async cleanup work that needs to be done which is why I use the cancellation token instead of just dropping the other futures when one fails. So this may be a clue as to why the construct isn't standardized.
